# Testing Flask -- Avoiding Circular Import

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-testing

I have been using Django for a while but decided to give Flask a try for my latest side project. Because I did not want my entire app in one file, I followed the documentation [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/packages/) to make my Flask app into a package. Crucially, these instructions introduce a sort of circular import:

> Every Python programmer hates them, and yet we just added some: circular imports (That’s when two modules depend on each other. In this case *views.py* depends on *__init__.py*). Be advised that this is a bad idea in general but here it is actually fine. The reason for this is that we are not actually using the views in *__init__.py* and just ensuring the module is imported and we are doing that at the bottom of the file.

Indeed, this has not yet caused any problems in my app and my app will not function if I remove this line. However, my side project has gotten large enough I decided to try writing unit tests for it, using [Flask-Testing](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Testing/). In all their documentation, they simply `from package import app` as normal, as in every submodule in my application. However, if I drop a `tests.py` in the main package directory and try this import, then try to run the tests, it fails with the circular import mentioned above:

```
File "/home/me/my_app/my_app/__init__.py", line 165, in <module>
  import views
File "/home/me/my_app/my_app/views.py", line 23, in <module>
  from my_app import app, db
ImportError: cannot import name app
```

In the documentation for Flask-Testing, as well as other places like the [Mega-Tutorial section on Unit Testing](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-vii-unit-testing), this import is done and seems to "just work". For me, however, this is the only time I have had a problem with this circular import. What have I missed?

Comment: What about write `import views` in `__init__.py` after defined `app = Flask(__name__)`? That should solve circular reference. Let me know if it is a good solution to you.

Answer (score 2):

As documented [here](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) your `my_app/__init__.py` should looks like:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
from my_app import views
```

Pay attention that `app` is defined **before** import `views` from your package. If you follow that rule you don't have any circular import issue.

Comment: `import views` was already the last line in my \_\_init__.py. Turns out it was something to do with trying to run the test with nose. I switched to `unittest.main()` and it worked fine. Still never could get nose to work no matter what I tried.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist OK I don't know nose at all, so I cannot help you... sorry. Just a tip: double check your python path when you run nose's test, it seams that there is another `my_app` that is resolved as instead your package. Try to print your python path just before the include in `views`

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Do you have a `my_app` module in `my_app` package? If it is the case I guess you are falling down in the second last clause described [here](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/finding_tests.html)